# Stop Div from Scrolling out of View

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering if it is possible to stop a div from scrolling out of view?
http://jsfiddle.net/8uLuN/3/

If you click on the 1st link "About us" the div expands and reveals the content.  However when you click on the 2nd link "How We Work", the title bar scrolls out of view and reveals the bottom half of the content?  It seems to occur specifically when you declare:

```
ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small {
height: 1000px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium {
height: 1000px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large {
height: 1000px;
}
```

In contrast, the problem doesn't occur when the content is only a few lines or the div is about 100-200 or so pixels.

Is there a way to overcome this problem so the "How We Work" title bar comes into view and is visible (with the content below) without having to try a completely different approach?

Cheers
Volterony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a jQuery answer but it can be put into javascript by someone who actually knows it. :/

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        },500);
});
```

Comment: Does this just go anywhere in the JS file?

Comment: you'll have to include JQuery if you want to use this solution.

Comment: @Volterony it goes here `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here });` Make sure to include jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery

```
$("div").click(function(){
        $("body").scrollTop($(this).offset().top);
});
```

although you might want to give your menu divs a class and call it by that

lets assume you gave them a class of "***menuDiv***"

```
$(".menuDiv").click(function(){
        $("body").scrollTop($(this).offset().top);
});
```

else if you don't want to use Jquery

put an onclick for your div and add this in the function

```
scrollTo(window.pageXOffset,this.offsetTop);
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick mike.  I included JQuery and using your first example. Thank you very much for your help.